# prepare statement Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in c://... update

Tags: php, mysql

**estoy haciendo un update con una sentencia preparada pero cuando pongo en funcionamiento el siguiente codigo, me genera un error**

```
            $idfoto = 100;
            $idproforzz = "var";

            $sqlsx = "UPDATE productos_forzz SET id_img_forzz = ?  where 
            sku_producto_id = ?";

            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($con,$sqlsxs);

            $stmt2->bind_param("is",$idfoto, $idproforzz);
            $stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: Estas usando PDO para conectarte a la base de datos?

Comment: El metodo mysqli_prepare devuelve un false en caso de que la conexion no se realice, verifica antes del llamado al metodo bind_param mediante un var_dump($stmt2); cual es el valor de $stmt2

Comment: @Jesús si estimado jesus estoy usando pdo para conectarme de hecho hice un insert  que si funciona

Comment: @AnibalOspina   gracias anibal, me devuele un valor false /bool(false)    , la query igual la puse a funcionar a travez de la consola de mysql y me funciono no entiendo por que no funciona :/ a travez de php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable en la cual almacenas la consulta se llama $sqlsx y la que envías a la función mysqli_prepare es $sqlsxs